# Data Scraping howlongtobeat.com with python3, beautiful soup, and selenium(maybe)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Wondering what the the best way would be to scrape multiple urls from howlongtobeat.com would be

I'm trying to put a spreadsheet together and need this data

my idea is to us python3, beautifulsoup, and selenium but am not sure the best way to go about it

I'm using Linux (ubuntu 18.04) command console and could use a few tips (very new to this)

This is the code I have so far:

```
url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=38050'

response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

game_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'li.short:nth-of-type(2)')

first_game = game_containers[0]
first_game.text
```

There is an error that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After that this returns:

```
'\nGod of War (2018) '
```

What I want from this is the "30 1/2 Hours" from the page (ideally 30.5 but I think I can use excel for that unless there is a way to do it during this stage)

Let me know how I would do this

do I need selenium?

Thanks,

Comment: since the info you want from the page doesn't get loaded by javascript, you shouldn't need selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
game_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='game_times')
```

returns a `ResultSet` of the `game_times` statistics table.

Use `[-1]` to get the last item, and get its `text`:

```
print(game_containers[-1].find_all({'li': '    short time_100 shadow_box'})[-1].contents[3].get_text())
```

prints:
`30½ Hours`